# Having trouble trying to convert iso to img for usb install, says "No such file or directory"

Tags: installation, usb, iso

Attempting to convert .ISO to .IMG for USB install, here is the line of code: `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.img ~/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso`. After trying to execute the command terminal says "No such file or directory".

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong, is there a space where it shouldn't be or do I have something backwards, I don't know, I just need some help, so I can make this USB install work.

Comment: You should not have typed in what (any of us) are suggesting exactly as we state. You should be filling in the 'explicitpath' and 'path/to/filename' parts with what YOU know those parts to be. That's the problem, I think.  If you aren't familiar with how to find the explicit path to a filename, we can help there instead.

Comment: is the file in that directory? What's the output of `ls ~/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.img`?

Answer (score 0):

In short: "Where is the file you saved at?"

---

A few things to try/consider:

1. The `~/` portion of your question assumes that the file exists in your main `/home/` folder for your user.  Where (exactly) is the file located?
2. Have you tried... `hdiutil convert /ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.img -format UDRW -o /ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso` instead?

It sounds like you're just not finding the file wherever it was that you saved it, originally... hence, "no such file or directory," and it's unlikely located in your main home/top folder.  It's probably in `~/downloads/` or something like that.

Comment: Have not tried "hdiutil convert /explicitpath/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.img -format UDRW -o /explicitpath/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso", but I will. I moved the file, it''s located on the top of Macintosh HD, the same place as the Users file and Applications file.

Comment: Tried your code suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work, thank you though.

Comment: Wait.. why is the file "at the top of your Mac HD"?  Please state, explicitly, the /path/to/the/filename.ext.  Do you understand what we are asking for you to provide?  If not, please say so, and I'll provide some help in that vein instead.

Comment: When I right click the file and choose the "get info" option under where it says, Where:/, I'm hoping that helps, if not maybe I don't understand what you asking and that probably where my problem is.

Comment: So, then, the correct syntax would be in my re-edited answer above. Try again, using the new code.

Comment: I'd also like to suggest that if you're not as familiar with command line syntax and/or folder structure you hold off on installing Raring (13.04) until you're a little more aware of how these things function.  13.04 is a Beta release, and you'll likely run into some more issues with it, as not everything works with it as intended just yet (it's not a fully 'supported' release yet - just a 'test' version).

Comment: It didn't work, but thank you again anyways. Maybe I should just stick with 12.04, had been using it for a while until the computer I was using finally just gave in. Someone gave me a free three year old macbook pro, so I figured I don't anything about OS X, I'll just but Ubuntu on it and be back in familiar territory, but anyways thanks for the help.

Comment: I would recommend you look at this: http://www.linux.org/article/view/basic-directory-structure-of-linux and then use the arrows left/right up at the top of that page to give you some more basic understanding of commands and navigating directories/files in Linux.  I imagine that the file you saved simply needs to be put back in your Linux users' home folder, and your original question's code will work.  Don't be discouraged!  ;)  You can still get this working, and you'll learn something in the process if you stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o /path/to/file.img /path/to/file.iso
```

Comment: Used the "sudo" command and it asked for the password and of course the previous owner didn't not know it, so going to run system restore and get admin control and attempt again to see if the "sudo"command works, fingers crossed. Thank you.

Comment: The syntax in this answer is wrong and will throw up an error with "No such file or directory."

Comment: @cksum The syntax is right, you just have to make sure the path is correct.  I've used it many times.

Comment: @Mitch That's strange because I tried it and it gave me the error in the original question. I references Ubuntu's official guide on converting an image and they use the syntax I put in my answer. That one worked no problem. Using your method always resulted in an error even though the path to the file was correct.